# elements in array is not working with in_array

Tags: php, laravel

number 3 should be in array $songsid but when i used in_array method output was null
nuder my function is dd($songsid)

```
public function index()
{
    $songs = Song::latest()->paginate(20);
    $songid = Collection::select("song_id")->where("user_id", "=", auth::user()->id)->get();
    
    $songsid = $songid->toArray();
    // dd($songsid);
    if(in_array(3, $songsid))
    {
        dd("yes");
    }
    else
    {
        dd("no");
    }
    
}
```

output of `$songsid` array `dd($songsid)`

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "song_id" => 3
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "song_id" => 2
  ]

]
```

Comment: `in_array` only checks the top level values. 3 is not on the top level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$songsid` is not an array of scalar values, but an array of arrays.
You could use `array_column()` to extract IDs from the array,

```
in_array(3, array_column($songsid, 'song_id')
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `in_array` method, you need an indexed array, ex : `$songsid = [3,2];`  You can use [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck) method :

```
$songsid = $songid->pluck('id')->toArray();
    
if(in_array(3, $songsid))
{
    dd("yes");
} else {
    dd("no");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you really need to convert to array, you could use collection methods to check that out.

```
$songid = Collection::select("song_id")->where("user_id", "=", auth::user()->id)->get();

if ($songId->contains('song_id', 3)) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

in_array() searches in the array values, that is not nesting.
You may want to use array_culumn() like
`in_array(3, array_column($songsid, 'song_id')`

or search for `['song_id' => 3]` like
`in_array(3, array_column($songsid, ['song_id' => 3])`